# how do I handle a situation in which the method in the method run () is taking parameters?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have method like this:

```
public void rentBook(ArrayList<book> list, Book book)
{
    if(!list.isEmpty())
    {


        list.remove(book);
        book.setAvailable(false);
        Biblioteka.listOfRented.add(book);

    }           

    else
        System.out.println("No any books left");
}
```

and I want to invoke this method in run() method of Thread. I'm making library system and I want to make the reade ( thread) can rent book (method rentBook )   I have no idea how can I correctly pass parameters. Any tips :/?

Comment: You need the parameters to be available in the scope of the `Thread`'s `run` method, e.g. you pass them in as constructor parameters and store them in fields, have them defined as `final` local variables in the containing scope etc.

Comment: What parameters would you need to pass?

Comment: Llike in method- one list of books and second which book of this list- it make it look like percon coud pick which book want to rent. So there is no any other way than passing it through construcotor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, here's two (compiling, running) ways you can do it:

```
public void methodUsingFinals() {
    final ArrayList<book> list = new ArrayList<>();
    final Book currentBook = new Book();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            rentBook(list, currentBook);
        }
    });
}

public void methodAcceptingValues(ArrayList<book> list, Book currentBook) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            rentBook(list, currentBook);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew :)